# What is Constraint in kind signature

Tags: haskell, type-kinds, constraint-kinds

If I inspect the `kind` of `Maybe` I get this:

```
λ> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
```

Now, if I inspect the kind of `Monad` I get this:

```
λ> :k Monad
Monad :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
```

What is `Constraint` there and why it is needed ? Why not just this `* -> *` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Unlike `Maybe`, `Monad` is not a *type*; it is a *typeclass*.**

The same goes for other typeclasses:

```
Num :: * -> Constraint
Functor :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
Bifunctor :: (* -> * -> *) -> Constraint
```

Where `*` represents concrete types (such as `Bool` or `Int`), `->` represent higher-kinded types (such as `Maybe`), and `Constraint` represents the idea of a type constraint. This is why:

---

As we know we can't make a signature like this:

```
return :: a -> Monad a -- This is nonsense!
```

Because `Monad` should be used as a *constraint*, to say that, 'this must be a monad to work':

```
return :: (Monad m) => a -> m a
```

We do this because we know that `return` can't work on any old type `m`, so we define the behaviour of `return` for different types under the name `Monad`. In other words, *there is no single thing that can be called a Monad, but only behaviour that can be called Monadic.*

For this reason, we have created this type constraint, saying that we must have pre-defined something as a Monad to use this function. This is why the kind of `Monad` is `(* -> *) -> Constraint` - it itself is not a type!

---

`Maybe` is an instance of `Monad`. This means that somewhere, someone has written:

```
instance Monad Maybe where
  (>>=) = ... -- etc
```

...and defined how `Maybe` should behave as a Monad. This is why we can use `Maybe` with functions or types that have the prefix constraint `Monad m => ...`. This is essentially where one defines the constraint applied by `Monad`.

Answer (score 8):

`Constraint` is the kind of e.g. `Show Int`, `Monad Maybe`, and `Monoid [a]`. Roughly, it is the kind of everything that can occur on the left side of `=>` in type annotations.

Now since

```
Show Int :: Constraint
```

and `Int` is a type, i.e.

```
Int :: *
```

we can assign a functional kind to `Show` as follows

```
Show :: * -> Constraint
             ^-- the result kind
        ^-- the kind of Int
```

In your case it just happens that a `Monad` takes argument like `Maybe`, so

```
Maybe Int :: *
Maybe :: * -> *
Monad :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
                     ^-- the result kind
         ^-- the kind of Maybe
```