# Higher kinded type on typeclass?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-kinds, constraint-kinds

To find out, if a type is a higher kinded type ghci provide:

```
Prelude> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
```

And tried on typeclass like:

```
Prelude> :k Functor
Functor :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
```

Why can I ask for higher kinded type on typeclass? What does **constraint** mean?

Comment: Closely related: [*What is Constraint in kind signature*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29509786/2751851); [*What does has kind 'Constraint' mean in Haskell*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41121107/2751851) (note the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41123141/2751851) addresses your question more directly than the accepted one).

Comment: (I haven't closed as a duplicate myself because I'm not sure about which of the three questions would make for a better duplicate target, and also because your "Why can I ask for higher kinded type on typeclass?" might be hinting at a somewhat more general question. That being so, I will leave it up to you and/or the other readers to decide.)

Comment: I went ahead and closed this question as a duplicate. Is there any part of it that you feel the linked questions do not cover?